How to calculate the distance between two vias in a Via Fence
I am designing a 2 layer PCB for an IoT application. Its a 2 layer PCB with onboard antennas for GSM and GNSS. The board uses wired communication protocols like I2C, CAN, UART and SPI. I have stitched all the high speed signals with vias but had questions regarding shielding the PCB with vias by stitching the ground planes on both the layers.
My limited understandings of shielding the PCB using vias is to decrease electromagnetic interferences from outside the board on my signals (Let me know if there are some other reasons on why stitching the ground planes is recommended).
For now, the shielding vias are placed around all the unused area(consisting of no routing) as shown.

From this article[1], 
I calculated that the minimum distance between my shielding vias should be minimum 39.5mm (L=λ/4 and λ=c/f, so in our case max frequency we are operating at is 1900MHz). So theoritically my design should be fine and my design does not exactly contain any high speed signals so I dont feel it should be much prone to noise from the enviornment.
What factors do i consider while placing stitching and shielding vias?
In my current calculations Do i also need to consider the disturbances coming from other signals present in the enviornment? Should I be cautious about 5GHz signals from the enviornment? Would they cause interference on the board? If so ill maintain distance between shielding vias less than 3.7mm (calculated for 5GHz disturbances from the enviornment)
I dont have much expertize with hardware design can you please suggest some good material that can help me wrap my brain around the concept of vias

There are harmonics and they have a different wave length. In a robust design you need to consider up to the n th harmonic. For whatever n that is sensible - that's when it gets subjective.

As for the environment, you'll always pick up stay RF from a very broad range of frequencies. Yes you need to keep this in mind by applying filters and decoupling caps.

Err... btw... doing RF with 2 layer boards is a very bad idea. Consider spending $0.1 more per PCB instead of spending $10000 more per failed EMC test.

@Lundin, Could you elaborate a bit more on the harmonics point?
Yes, I have added filtering networks on the GSM and GNSS antenna traces and these components have been tuned to reduce noise on the bands I am operating at using a VNA too, Is there anything else that I need to consider to mitigate the chances of picking up noise from other frequencies?
Sure I'll consider upgrading to a 3-layer (One ground plane sandwiched) or 4-layer(A ground and a power plane) board.

RF design and EMC are big topics and I'm by no means an expert. 4 layers is standard, what stack-up to go for kind of depends on if it is single-sided or double-sided mounting and where the RF parts go. As for vias they are pretty much free so just spam 'em as tight as you can alongside the RF paths and ground to copper pour just below. Addressing EMC without a schematic + layout isn't gonna go very far either.

As for harmonics, that's your carrier frequency x2 then x3 then x4... each with a higher frequency and shorter wave length. So the via-to-via formula based on the carrier is a bit fishy. EMC tests often fail on harmonics rather than the fundamental and many radio standards are far less lenient about noise that far from your intentional frequency.

For example the ETSI standards for radio in Europe are quite lenient around the fundamental where there's certain limitations for occupied bandwidth. You can get away with all manner of noise there such as semiduplex PA switching on and off. But when you go out of the occupied bandwith then everything is considered spurious emissions and there's some -37dBm limit for transmitters and even lower for receivers iirc.

That probably isn't quite the right way to calculate via distances.  It seems unlikely that you will even need the shielding vias around your signals, but also be able use a 2-layer board with vias that far apart.
Protecting your signals from interference is important, but it can be even more important to protect the rest of your board/system/world from your signals.
It would be a shame if your signals were perfect, but the information they were sending was wrong anyhow because an earlier communication had interfered with your measurement, or with antenna reception.  (Though if you're shielding SPI and I2C, I assume you have also shielded antenna feeds.)
If your systems works perfectly (according to your functional specifications), but emits too much interference, then you can't legally sell it.  (Thus the September 27, 12:03 comment from @Lundin about the expense of a failed EMC test.)
For shielding the rest of the world from your signals, it doesn't matter how much information you are actually sending; it instead matters how quickly your voltages are changing. So the relevant "wavelength" is instead based on the signal rise time (or fall time, if that is faster).  Even a "slow" protocol will be a problem if your actual device is fast enough to produce nearly square waves.  (So updating an old design to a modern part can cause emissions to start failing.)
The source you quoted did mention λ/4, but also mentioned λ/10 and λ/20.  There are plenty of designs that don't bother to shield at all; if you're being careful enough to explicitly shield anything beyond antenna feeds, you should probably go with at least the λ/10 suggestion.  (But that is an "if".)
Also note that intentional signals aren't the only source of noise; your integrated circuits will probably radiate at their clock frequency, though that will mostly be conducted over your power/ground nets and only interfere with your own system.  You can probably ignore this, unless some of your sensors are particularly sensitive.  (If your "ground" reference varies by some tens of millivolts, will that be a problem?)
One reason not to use 2-layer boards when you care about interference is that the ground plane will typically be on the other side of the board; with a 4-layer board, it will often be closer by an order of magnitude, which will help with both emissions and avoiding interference.  The conducting layers are not usually evenly spaced; you can look at the suggested layer stackup from your fabricator and see how thick the core or pre-preg layers are.  (These will both usually be called substrate or dielectric when you find a formula.)
Now back to that "if" you need it ... Eric Bogatin generally recommends against ground fill.  That extra grounding (letting you have a coplanar wave guide instead of just stripline/microstrip) is helpful, but usually not by enough to matter, and it opens up at least a chance for mistakes that do make enough difference to matter.  Now note that if you can usually just skip that ground wrapping (by simply separating the traces from each other by a little more) ... then you won't have anywhere to via stitch to ... and yet that often does work.
